# JS - displaying annotations on html5 video element

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube, annotations

```
<video id="video" preload=auto autoplay controls>
<source src = "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">


</video>
```

Youtube uses notes once a user defines one in his videos. 
they are called annotations. Something like this:
http://www.incomediary.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/types-of-youtube-annotations.jpg

Is there an easy way to display it on a specific X, Y on my video,
full screen or not? for certain reasons,
I don't want the notes to be displayed on a canvas, 
just on a video. How does youtube do it? I suspect that
they don't use canvas, since when right clicking on their videos show it's a video element.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, the annotations should be able to display dynamically - for example it can be displayed all of the sudden at minute 5:33, because maybe JS received something from Node server stating so.